# base64 regex that filters unwanted results

Tags: r, regex, base64

Filter unwanted matches from the regular expression

I'm extracting base64 encode strings in R and I'm using the following regex:

`\b[A-Za-z0-9+/]\b`

99% of the time works OK, but when I have cases like this (or similar):

```
itisyourpersonalenergyspecialistitisyourpersonalenergyspecialist
```

where I have words collapsed I get matches. My data is messy and comes like that.

Is there any way to filter them out modifying my original regex.

The question might be obvious but I'm relatively new to regular expressions.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get as your output?

Comment: You will always have false positives, normal words can be valid base64 strings. If you want to limit the regex to some specific base64 string subset please indicate these requirements.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what this does `\b[A-Za-z0-9+/]\b`. Is it a single character,  class surrounded by word boundary constructs ?

Answer (score 0):

> You might consider designing several boundaries on an expression for
> that 1% probability that you may have and occur.

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Rqqqnz/1/) might help you to design such expression, simply using adding some boundaries like:

- Should have certain chars using `(?=)` followed by a number of occurrence `{n,}` (even though this is not the best boundary, it might help you to design one, I'm not really sure about base64)
- You can also add a length boundary around your `\b( )\b` to not match the exampled string that you may have with low percent probability.

You can see that the probability of a string like:

```
 itisyourpersonalenergyspecialistitisyourpersonalenergyspecialist
```

being a base64 string is pretty much `0`. Even if you have some random strings a little close to base64 format, maybe something similar to the one I have highlighted, still a good expression can simply exclude that.

You can add so many types of boundaries to reach almost 100% accuracy, if you wish. This is not a good expression, but it might give you the general view:

```
(?=.+[A-Z]{2,})(?=.+[a-z]{2,})(?=.+[0-9]{2,})([A-Za-z0-9+\/]{100,})
```

This expression simply might mean that, the string input:

- must have a minimum of two [A-Z] chars next to each other.
- must contain a minimum of two [a-z] chars next to each other.
- must contain a minimum of two [0-9] chars next to each other (which I'm so sure about this one).
- should have a minimum of 100 base64 char length.

[image]

You might consider that those quantifiers that I have added such as `{2,}` and `{100,}`, was just to simply show that you can exclude a string as exampled in your question. You can most likely design a myriad of much better expressions for this matching that you wish to pass a 100% accuracy.

---

#### Additional Demo:

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Lsal1x/1/) might help you to see how the quantifier works:

```
 ([A-Za-z0-9+\/]{100,})
```

[image]

> Overall, you can certainly do so.